# Triple Integral Conversion from Cartesian to Polar: Any multivariable calculus wiz that could confirm that I did this correctly?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I'm currently taking multivariable/vector calculus and I'm struggling.  It's been well over a year since I took calculus 2, and way longer than that since calculus 1 so I'm trying to play catch-up on old material while learning the new stuff.

I'd really appreciate feedback about my solution to a question asking me to convert a Cartesian coordinate triple integral into an integral in cylindrical coordinates.

Apart from feedback/confirmation, my main concern relates to the integration limits of theta.  I'm having a hard time understanding the text on this, and relevant material I've found tends to skimp on the details.  I am going to graph the integration limits to get a better idea of what's going on in this problem, but I frequently run out of time during exams and feel that I need to be confident in setting these up through algebra alone.

The problem and attempted solution can be found in the link below. I'm new to the site and it won't allow me to imbed the image in the post.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/quLFl.jpg

For anyone who gave this a read, thank you for taking the time, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: My reasoning for choosing 0 <= theta <= 2pi for theta are as follows: y = (9-x^2)^(1/2) converted to r = sqrt(9), and x [-3, 3] seemed to imply that when r is at its maximum/minimum, theta needs to be 0 or a multiple of 2pi for r = 3/cos(theta) and r = -3/cos(theta) to be true.  Its clear that this is a cylinder with a radius of 3 and a height of 2, so the limit of theta needs to be such that it can produce the full circle for the cylinder, hence 0 <= theta <= 2pi.  Is my reasoning sound?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the heads up.  If you don't mind explaining, what is the proper way to write mathematical equations in posts?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).